# dynamically load assembly whose references packed with LIBZ

Tags: .net, dynamic, .net-assembly, libz

My question is whether it is possible at all to dynamically load a CLR assembly that have all the assemblies it references packed within by **LibZ** solution. If I try to just use an Assembly.Load() it doesn't seem to work (BTW the Telerik's   JustDecompile does not see them also). I hope anyone has stumbled upon this problem with this particular setup or may know some of the quirks involved. Maybe some manipulations that I can do within the ResolveEventHandler event?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Well, after digging through the LibZ code I've realized that it should work as expected and tried to investigate other directions. Turned out that there was an assembly with broken strong name signature, but since native dll calls the CLI proxy dll which in turn performs dynamic loading I couldn't debug into or resolve for descriptive error messages so now it's clear.

Regards

Comment: Also after delving into LibZ it's clear why JustDecompile  refuses to see the references - it loads the assembly for reflection only purposes which doesn't activate the Libz embedded resolver.